# Terraform API Gateway resources from yaml with loop

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

Hi I need create multiple API gateway resource with method, method response, integration,integration response and stage. Would like do it from yaml config like

```
endpoints:
  first_man:
    methods:
     default: OPTIONS
     second: GET
  second_women:
    methods:
     default: OPTIONS
     second: POST
```

I except get endpoint resource, and methods and integration defined  in (default and second) How I should describe terraform with for_each?

I have

```
locals {
config= yamldecode(file("${path.module)/config.yml"))
}



resource 'aws_api_gateway_method' default {
   for_each = local.config.endpoints

}

resource 'aws_api_gateway_method' second {
   for_each = local.config.endpoints

}
```

etc.

Comment: Do you have an example of what would be inside of the `config.yml` file?

Comment: Hi, yes I edited question, yaml content in description

Comment: The API gateway's raw configuration model is pretty onerous to describe in Terraform because it appears as a tree of resources (requiring recursion) and because each method requires four resources that must be created in just the right order for things to work. For dynamic configuration as you are trying here I'd typically recommend ignoring most of the resource types and instead just using `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` with its `body` argument, specifying the entire API structure all at once as a single OpenAPI document. You can then generate the OpenAPI doc using Terraform expressions.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, thanks, openapi using it's a good point